# Delete shared pointer by memory address from vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a vector containing shared pointers. I want to remove a pointer from the list by using its memory address, is this possible? Or is there a better way to store a collection of shared pointers?

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Person>> list;

void removePerson(const std::shared_ptr<Person>& person) {
                auto remove = std::remove(list.begin(), list.end(), person);
                list.erase(remove, list.end());
    }
```

Comment: Does "its memory address" mean the value of the pointer (i.e. the memory location of the Person object the shared_ptr is pointing to), or the address of the pointer (i.e. the memory location of the shared_ptr object itself, located inside the vector's Internal items-array)?

Comment: If you want quick lookup by value, `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` will give you `O(log(N))` and `O(1)` lookup times respectively, either is significantly faster than the `O(N)` by-value lookup time of a `std::vector` (although the performance difference would only be noticeable if the number of shared_ptrs you are maintaining is large, e.g. hundreds/thousands or more)

Comment: Doesn't that call to `list.erase` delete all the items past the item to remove as well?

Comment: [`list.erase(remove);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) should be called to erase just that single item from the vector.

Comment: *is this possible?*  What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible to remove a pointer from a container of pointers by address.

While `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>` is *a* normal way of storing shared pointers, the question of which way is better can not be answered without knowing more about your requirements.

Here is an expansion of your template to demonstrate pointer removal by address, using your own `removePerson()` function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// A minimal Person type for demonstration purposes
struct Person {
    Person(const std::string& n): name(n) {}
    std::string name;
};

// Original template
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Person>> persons;

void removePerson(const std::shared_ptr<Person>& person) {
    auto remove = std::remove(persons.begin(), persons.end(), person);
    persons.erase(remove, persons.end());
}

int main()
{
    auto bob = std::make_shared<Person>("bob");

    // Include bob multiple times to demonstrate multiple removal
    persons.emplace_back(bob);
    persons.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Person>("alice"));
    persons.emplace_back(bob);
    persons.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Person>("carol"));
    persons.emplace_back(bob);

    // Define a lambda for debugging output
    auto printPersons = [&] (const auto& header) {
        std::cout << header << std::endl;
        for(auto& p: persons)
            std::cout << p->name << std::endl;
    };

    printPersons("== Before ==");
    removePerson(bob);
    printPersons("\n== After ==");
}
```

This yields the following output:

```
== Before ==
bob
alice
bob
carol
bob

== After ==
alice
carol
```

Note: A `std::vector` would usually not be named `list` because it's, well, not a list ;-)

Comment: Note that `std::remove()` will scan the entire vector. If the pointer is stored in the vector only once, you should use `std::find()` instead, and then `erase()` the sole iterator that is returned if it is not the end iterator.